# What routing system support off-road routing for Leaflet integration?

Tags: leaflet, routing

I have a collection of regionally specific linestrings and multi-line strings which are off-road paths. I would like to be able to integrate these into a Leaflet routing systems which would exclusively use these paths and no other existing roads/trails. From the research so far, it looks like I could use perliedman leaflet-routing-engine to hook into ORSM or Valhalla, but then I would need to feed the custom off-road paths into these systems. I would like to keep these paths private for at least a period of time.

Is building these out in OSM as private the best option for feeding the routing system?

Is there a better way to just feed these paths into ORSM or Valhalla directly?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. As a new user, please take the [Tour].  We are not a discussion forum. Instead, we use a Focused question/Best answer model, which does not work well with *opinion-based* questions.

Answer (score 0):

If you have PostGIS/pgRouting already installed, you could use something like [lrm-pgrouting](https://github.com/sanak/lrm-pgrouting). It does not seem very active right now, but I used it pretty successfully a few years ago, to do something very similar to what you want.